# {placeholder} handling in IBM Bluemix Globalization Pipeline

Tags: ibm-cloud, globalization, globalization-pipeline

IBM Bluemix Globalization Pipeline handles space character around {placeholder} differently from language to language.  Are these intentional?

For example, "Version {version}” in English (note one space after "Version" is translated as follows in nine languages it supports.  I'd like it to keep space after バージョン in Japanese.

```js
de: "Version {version}”
es: "Versión { version }”
fr: "Version de { version }”
it: "Versione {version}”
ja: "バージョン{version}”
ko: "버전 {version}”
pt-BR: "Versão { version }”
zh-Hans: "版本{version}”
zh-Hant: "版本{version}”
```

Answer (score 3):

Machine translation engines currently used by Globlalization Pipeline beta do not understand variable parameter syntax used by programming languages. At this moment, Globalization Pipeline recognizes a pattern "{}", and preserves the original format, but it does not handle if the text enclosed by curly bracket is not digits.

It is unlikely that curly brackets are embedded in natural English text for translation, it is planned to protect such pattern as well as "{}" in near future.

Because Globalization Pipeline is designed to be programming language independent, future update may allow user to define variable patterns to be protected per bundle.